# Image Quality problems using bitmap

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

I'm a beginner in Android Studio and I'm trying to take a photo, using the default android camera, and save it in gallery in a specific folder but i have a problem with image quality. The image it's 
Please advice me what to change on my code

Here is my code:

```
public class AddPhoto extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_photo);

    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewimage);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddPhoto.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            1);

}

private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_CAM = 1;
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_GALLERY = 2;
private ImageView imageview;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/IKnow";



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddPhoto.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void takePhoto() {
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePhotoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PICTURE_CAM);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(AddPhoto.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(AddPhoto.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_CAM) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        saveImage(thumbnail);
        Toast.makeText(AddPhoto.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
public void buttonOnClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.cameraButton:

            takePhoto();
            break;

        case R.id.nextButton:

            Intent intent = new Intent (AddPhoto.this, MainActivity.class);
            AddPhoto.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Change this line   myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);  

to

  myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655543/camera-captured-image-is-uploading-to-a-server-with-very-poor-quality

Answer (score 2):

You are compressing bitmap in this line.

```
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
```

Change it to

```
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Answered above second parameter is for Quality
compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePhotoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PICTURE_CAM);
}
```

That will only give you a thumbnail of the image and the camera app threw away the full image so there is no image file.

You should add an

```
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileprovideruri ).
```

with which you tell the camera app where to store the image.

You are #12345 which encounters this android feature.

If you google a bit for extra_output you will find hundreds of stackoverflow posts handling your problem.

Comment: Of course it works. But if you dont want help. Well. Ok.

Comment: The preview of the image it's still blurred, ofc i want help, that's why i posted here.

Comment: Oh.. I dont see the code you tried and from which you just said that it did not work. Wrong way of asking help.

Comment: I tried like you advised, i don't have an error, but after i'm taking the photo, the preview it's still the same. I tried this even before asking here but i saw the preview still blurred and i thought nothing changed, i didn't checked gallery. But the photo it's ok after saving in gallery. I can remove the preview somehow or do something? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you consider to be a preview.

Comment: i can't upload an image here.. hmm.. after i'm taking the photo i see a preview with 2 options, OK and RETRY. After i press OK the image it's saved and the quality it's ok now, but that preview it's the same :(

Comment: That preview has norhing to do with your app. And all with the invoked camera app. Of course you have no influence on that camera app. Try another camera app or a different device. I do not recognise your problem.